# MVC/JQuery: Retreving values from HTML controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have some controls on my view like so:

```
    <td id="name<%=Model.ID%>" ><%=Html.TextBox("Name")%></td>
    <td id="intensity<%=Model.ID %>" ><%=Html.DropDownList("Intensities")%></td>
```

How can I retrieve the values of these controls with jQuery?

Something like:

```
var name = $("#name" + id).val();
alert(name);
```

Comment: btw Alex, you should tag your asp-net mvc questions with "asp.net-mvc" for better answers

Answer (score 1):

well since `<%=Html.TextBox("Name")%>` make an input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" />
you could just

```
var name = $("#Name").val(); alert(name);
var intensities = $("#Intensities").val(); alert(intensities );
```

Comment: Note that if you are using "User.Name" syntax, then the id will be rendered as id="User_Name"

Comment: It's basically a way to control the binding. If you have a Model with a User property on it, this is the best way to bind the User.Name. Both on rendering and on binding in the actionmethod's parameters that you post to.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reference the textbox the way you propose you will need to give the textbox a custom id like this, supposing you're iterating over a collection of users:

```
<%foreach(var user in Model.UserCollection){%>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Name",user.Name,new{id="name"+user.Id})%>
<%}%>
```